# Exporting Office 365 Auto-Fill Email Addresses to Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2007, office365

I have a user who is running Office 2007. I attemped to install Office 2016 alongside Office 2007, because the user needed the newer version of Excel. There were some issues, however, such as the PC not being able to select Outlook 2007 as the default email program (one of the problems with having to install all Office applications at once, rather than being able to choose.) I ended up uninstalling Office 2016.

The user is back on Outlook 2007, but it appears to have 'forgotten' the auto-complete email addresses that appear when typing in the To, CC or BCC fields.

The email account is on Office 365, and when logging on to the web portal and filling in the To, CC or BCC fields on there, it still auto-completes.

Is there a way to export this information from Office 365, and import it into Outlook 2007?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The auto-complete data for email addresses is saved into an 'N2K' file, located at:

> C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Outlook

There, I found that Outlook had created a new '%username%.N2K' file, and renamed the previous one to '%username%.N2K.old'.

All I needed to do was to delete the new file, remove the '.old' from the filename of the old, and restart Outlook 2007. This restored the auto-complete data.